# Factorial Formulae proof (from Algorithm Design Manual)

Tags: correctness-proof, summation

I'm going through Algorithm Design Manual and it didn't take long before I hit a proof I don't understand. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

From the book:

> *Problem*: Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n i * i! = (n + 1)! - 1$ by induction.
>
> *Solution*: The inductive paradigm is straightforward. First verify the basis case (here we do n = 1, although n = 0 would be even more general):
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^1 i * i! = 1 = (1 + 1)! - 1 = 2 - 1 = 1$
>
> Now assume the statement is true up to n. To prove the general case of n + 1,
> observe that rolling out the largest term
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i * i! = (n+1) * (n + 1)! + \sum_{i=1}^n i * i!$
>
> reveals the left side of our inductive assumption. Substituting the right side gives us
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i * i! = (n+1) * (n + 1)! + (n+1)! - 1$
>
> = $(n+1)! * ((n+1) + 1) -1$
>
> = $(n+2)! - 1$

I can follow this until the last line few lines.

I understand that he proves that it is indeed true for the base case of `n=1` that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i * i! = (n + 1)! - 1$$

Once he proves that he then takes the `n+1` case and expands out the summation to sum that plus the new upper bound

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i * i! = (n+1) * (n + 1)! + (n+1)! - 1$$

but then I don't understand how he then simplifies that

$$(n+1) * (n + 1)! + (n+1)! - 1$$

down to

$$(n+1)! * ((n+1) + 1) -1$$

what just happened there? how does $(n+1) * (n + 1)! + (n+1)! - 1$ equal $(n+1)! * ((n+1) + 1) -1$  ??

nor do i understand how he then simplifies that to

$$(n+2)! - 1$$

how does $(n+1)! * ((n+1) + 1) -1$ equal $(n+2)! - 1$ ??

Any help here is appreciated, my brain is hurting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any two numbers $a,b$, it is true that $ab + b = (a+1)b$ which is derived from simple algebra.

Now substitute $(n+1)!$ instead of $b$ and $(n+1)$ instead of $a$.

For the second problem you have, note that $(n+1+1) \cdot (n+1)!=(n+2)\cdot (n+1)!=(n+2)!$ by definition of the factorial function.

Comment: Thank you, this makes total sense now!

Comment: @hackerhasid Glad I can help!